# jquery on not working with variable selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic `div` that I want to trigger an event on mouseover.
I use jQuery `on` to trigger the event the selector is also dynamic and gets its content from a variable but its not working!
When I change the variable selector to a regular selector it works fine.

HTML:

```
<div class="div1"></div>

<textarea class="t" num="1"></textarea><button class="b" num="1">b1</button><br>
<textarea class="t" num="2"></textarea><button class="b" num="3">b2</button><br>
<textarea class="t" num="3"></textarea><button class="b" num="3">b3</button><br>
```

Javascript:

```
 $('*:not(body,html,.div1)').mouseover(function(){
     $(this).css({'border':'2px solid red'});
 });

 $('*:not(body,html,.div1)').mouseout(function(){
     $(this).css({'border':'none'});
 });

 var c1='';

 $('*:not(body,html,.div1)').click(function(){
     c1=$(this).attr('class');
     classes='<div id="'+c1+'">'+c1+'</div>';
     $('.div1').html(classes);
 });

 jQuery(document.body).on( 'mouseover', '#'+c1, function () {
    $('.'+c1).css({'border':'2px solid red'});
 });

 jQuery(document.body).on( 'mouseout', '#'+c1, function () {
    $('.'+c1).css({'border':'2px solid red'});
 });
```

Comment: So you want to change which elements are matched by handlers 4 and 5 based on which element was handled in handler 3? This seems very unlikely...

Comment: Whatever jquery you are using, use it after the dynamic contents are loaded into DOM. For example usually above closing body tag.

Comment: You need to declare the 'on' event in the click callback.

Comment: `c1` is an empty string when your code runs... were you expecting something different?

Comment: you're attaching the event before `c1` is defined (after div1 is clicked)

Comment: What is the exact functionality you're looking for? There might be an easier way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

You run your `on` methods, when `c1` is still an empty string. Run them inside the `click` method:

```
$('*:not(body,html,.div1)').click(function(){
    c1=$(this).attr('class');
    classes='<div id="'+c1+'">'+c1+'</div>';
    $('.div1').html(classes);

    jQuery(document.body).on( 'mouseover', '#'+c1, function () {
        $('.'+c1).css({'border':'2px solid red'});
    });

    jQuery(document.body).on( 'mouseout', '#'+c1, function () {
        $('.'+c1).css({'border':'2px solid red'});
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bind anything directly to the selected element on your `.div1`, where you can bind on the hover of this `.div1`, whatever it contains. You'll detect what it contains when you'll hover it.

You won't have to bother binding (**and unbinding**) each time you click an element.

You can take advantage of jQuery's built-in binders ([`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)) and chaining too, and you had your border disappearing (there are still problems for buttons) :

```
$('*:not(body,html,.div1)').hover(function () {
    $(this).css({
        'border': '2px solid red'
    });
}, function () {
    $(this).css({
        'border': '1px solid black'
    });
}).click(function () {
    var c1 = $(this).attr('class');
    var classesElement = $('<div></div>', {
        id: c1,
        html: c1
    });
    $('.div1').append(classes);
});

//Retrieve the contained element when you'll hover .div1
$('.div1').hover(function () {
    var selectedElementClass = $(this).children().attr('id');
    $('.' + selectedElementClass).css({
        'border': '2px solid red'
    });
}, function () {
    var selectedElementClass = $(this).children().attr('id');
    $('.' + selectedElementClass).css({
        'border': '1px solid black'
    });
});
```

I set up [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v8wSw/) in case you want to see how it works.